# Wrong anchor point for matplotlib pgf

Tags: pgfplots, hyperref

I have exported my curve from matplotlib using the [following guide](https://timodenk.com/blog/exporting-matplotlib-plots-to-latex/). But there is a problem with reference at y-axis label. You can see it on screenshot:
[image]

The red square should be at "1" in "(s. 1)". I did it with `\ref{...}` and included the `hyperref` library. The label will be initiated with the following line in pgf file:

```
\pgftext[x=0.469752in,y=2.376000in,,bottom,rotate=90.000000]{\color{textcolor}\rmfamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont Energiedichte \LaTeX \(\displaystyle \varphi\) (s. \ref{formel:wichtig}) [Js]}%
```

It seems that `\ref` (and even `\hyperref`) annotation doesn't use rotate parameter. Is it some kind of bug in it? What can be a possible way of soltion this problem?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JohnKormylo. There is no axis environment. I have shared the related code to pastebin [link](https://pastebin.com/mmdB6UST)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does look like a problem specific to `\pgftext`.  You can fix it by using `\rotatebox` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\refstepcounter{figure}\label{formel:wichtig}
\hrule
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgftext[x=0.469752in,y=2.376000in]{\rotatebox{90}{\color{black}\rmfamily\fontsize{10.000000}{12.000000}\selectfont Energiedichte \LaTeX \(\displaystyle \varphi\) (s. \ref{formel:wichtig}) [Js]}}%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That helps! But now the label overlapped the axis [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Q223W2E.png). I understand that this can be fixed with chaning of x coordinate, but how can I calculate the difference of them and where does the problem come from?

Comment: \rotatebox can adjust the center of rotation. The default is. [origin=bl] or [origin=Bl] so [origin=c] or [origin=cb] should do it. Documentation is from the graphicx manual.

Comment: That's true, but doesn't help. Seems like anchorpoint should be right on edge of the box, otherwise it's still the same...

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. If I am ready to contribute code base can you explain, where the problem occures? In hyperref or basically in ref?

Comment: You can put a \ref inside a savebox and rotate the savebox, no problem.  The weirdness comes from \pgftext.